# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).initialize is not a function after bundling

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I'm using System.Web.Optimization.dll to bundle my javascript file 
I had 2 different Bundle

```
 var jsBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/Content/scripts/jsBundle")
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/external/modernizr.2.6.2.js") // 2.6.2
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/external/jquery.js") // 1.9.1 min
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/external/jquery.migrate.js") // 1.1.1 min
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/external/jquery-ui.js") // 1.10.2
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/external/jquery.cookie.js")
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/external/jquery.touchpunch.js") // 0.2.2
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/external/jquery.toggle.button.js")
                .Include("~/Content/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js") //2.3.2
                .Include("~/Content/mcustomscrollbar/mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js")
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/external/jquery.masonry.min.js") //2.1.08
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/external/jquery.jnotify.min.js")
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/external/jquery.dynatree.js")
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/external/jquery.form.js")
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/external/WhenReady.js")
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/external/bbq.js")
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/external/select2.js")
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/external/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/external/jquery.querystring.js")
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/external/jquery.dropdown.js")
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/external/jquery.hotkeys.js")
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/kendo/kendo.all.min.js")
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/external/wysiwym/showdown.js")
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/external/wysiwym/wysiwym.js")
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/external/jquery.poshytip.js")
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/external/ToolTips.js")
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/external/jquery.placeholder.js")
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/external/jquery.selection.js")
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/external/snap.js")
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/external/chosen.jquery.js")
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/external/jquery.elevatezoom.js");

        jsBundle.Orderer = nullOrderer;
        bundles.Add(jsBundle);
```

and

```
var calendarJsBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/Content/external/calendarJsBundle")
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/external/FrontierCalendar/colorpicker/colorpicker.js")
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/external/FrontierCalendar/jquery-qtip-1.0.0-rc3140944/jquery.qtip-1.0.js")
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/external/FrontierCalendar/lib/jshashtable-2.1.js")
                .Include("~/Content/scripts/external/FrontierCalendar/frontierCalendar/jquery-frontier-cal-1.3.2.js");
            calendarJsBundle.Orderer = nullOrderer;
            bundles.Add(calendarJsBundle);
```

and when I merge both together my initialize method not recognized by browser.

this line of code works properly

```
$('#mycal').initialize("/admin/Events/CalendarNextView", "True", "20", "/brainbank-default/admin/Events");
```

but after merging both together 
I got Uncaught TypeError: $(...).initialize is not a function

Comment: Let's see your merged version that isn't working

Comment: How can I paste that here? , It's to much.